# Javascript function that merges objects based on values of the keys and restructures them based on values of the keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-structures, merge

I am trying to write a javascript function that receives at least two parameters - **array of objects** and **empty nested object**.

Array of objects contain objects that are not nested. All of them have same keys, but some keys might have different values. Each key name is something like "primary key" on certain level of nesting. Where the key should hold place as *"primary key"* is defined by empty nested object.

Empty nested object defines which key is *"primary key"* for which level of nesting. It defines the structure we need the final merged object to be.

The function should find and merge together all objects in array of objects, that have same value for the key thats first in **empty nested object** AND is type of object. However, because the objects hold other keys that have the same name but might have different values, if merged instantly, **we would lose the different values**.

So it takes value of last key that was found in empty nested object and was type of object, and creates a new key with name of that value and makes it a object. Inside it, it creates the name of key that this object is from, creates the key with same name and assigns it that value.

Then it keeps doing the same, based on empty nested object. In other words, the function is keep looking on **empty nested object** and checks if on the current level there is any other key thats type of object, before merging all objects together. It is merging the keys with same values from the bottom up.

All keys dont necessarily have to be *"primary keys"* on some level. These keys are present inside "DATA" level. In "DATA" might also appear a key that was a *"primary key"* on some level. Again, this is defined by **empty nested object**.

## Example of **empty nested object**:

```
{
            PERSON: {
                CRT: {
                    CRT_VALUE: {
                        CRT: null,
                        CODE: {
                            CODE_VALUE: {
                                CODE: null,
                                DATA: {
                                    CODE: {
                                        VALUE: null,
                                        META: null,
                                        NAME: null
                                    },
                                    NAME: {
                                        VALUE: null,
                                        META: null,
                                        NAME: null
                                    },
                                    SUM: {
                                        VALUE: null,
                                        META: null,
                                        NAME: null
                                    },
                                    CONTEXT: {
                                        VALUE: null,
                                        META: null,
                                        NAME: null
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

## Example of **array of objects**:

```
[
    {
        PERSON: "21",
        CODE: "CMSS",
        CONTEXT: "",
        NAME: "SALARY",
        CRT: "Common",
        SUM: 162000
    },
    {
        PERSON: "21",
        CODE: "DOS",
        CONTEXT: "",
        NAME: "TAX",
        CRT: "Common",
        SUM: 192000
    },
    {
        PERSON: "21",
        CODE: "UPL",
        CONTEXT: "",
        NAME: "WAGE",
        CRT: "Other",
        SUM: 255000
    },
    {
        PERSON: "22",
        CODE: "CMSS",
        CONTEXT: "",
        NAME: "SALARY",
        CRT: "Common",
        SUM: 150000
    }
]
```

The **final array of objects** should be merged based on values of the keys and based on **empty nested object**.

## **For given examples, the **final array of objects** should look like this:**

```
[
        {
            PERSON: "21",
            CRT: {
                "Common": {
                    CRT: "Common",
                    CODE: {
                        "CMSS": {
                            CODE: "CMSS",
                            DATA: {
                                NAME: {
                                    VALUE: "SALARY",
                                    META: undefined,
                                    NAME: "NAME",
                                },
                                SUM: {
                                    VALUE: 162000,
                                    META: undefined,
                                    NAME: "SUM",
                                },
                                CONTEXT: {
                                    VALUE: "",
                                    META: undefined,
                                    NAME: "CONTEXT",
                                },
                                CODE: {
                                    VALUE: "CMSS",
                                    META: undefined,
                                    NAME: "CODE",
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "DOS": {
                            CODE: "DOS",
                            DATA: {
                                NAME: {
                                    VALUE: "TAX",
                                    META: undefined,
                                    NAME: "NAME",
                                },
                                SUM: {
                                    VALUE: 192000,
                                    META: undefined,
                                    NAME: "SUMA",
                                },
                                CONTEXT: {
                                    VALUE: "",
                                    META: undefined,
                                    NAME: "KONTEXT",
                                },
                                CODE: {
                                    VALUE: "DOS",
                                    META: undefined,
                                    NAME: "CODE",
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                },
                "Other": {
                    CRT: "Other",
                    CODE: {
                        "UPL": {
                            CODE: "UPL",
                            DATA: {
                                NAME: {
                                    VALUE: "WAGE",
                                    META: undefined,
                                    NAZEV: "NAME",
                                },
                                SUM: {
                                    VALUE: 255000,
                                    META: undefined,
                                    NAZEV: "SUM",
                                },
                                CONTEXT: {
                                    VALUE: "",
                                    META: undefined,
                                    NAME: "CONTEXT",
                                },
                                CODE: {
                                    VALUE: "UPL",
                                    META: undefined,
                                    NAME: "CODE",
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            PERSON: "22",
            CRT: {
                "Common": {
                    CRT: "Common",
                    CODE: {
                        "CMSS": {
                            CODE: "CMSS",
                            DATA: {
                                NAME: {
                                    VALUE: "SALARY",
                                    META: undefined,
                                    NAME: "NAME",
                                },
                                SUM: {
                                    VALUE: 150000,
                                    META: undefined,
                                    NAME: "SUM",
                                },
                                CONTEXT: {
                                    VALUE: "",
                                    META: undefined,
                                    NAME: "CONTEXT",
                                },
                                CODE: {
                                    VALUE: "CMSS",
                                    META: undefined,
                                    NAME: "CODE",
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
```

The **function should be generic**, so it works for any given array of objects, and any given empty nested object - however, empty nested object must always have defined structure by the key names.

The array of objects must (will) always contain all the needed keys based on empty nested object.

## **What I tried and did not work:**

```
const mergeObjectsByKey = (array, key, newObject = {}, level = 1) => {
            let newObjects = []
            array.forEach(obj => {
                let currentObject = newObject;
                for (let k of Object.keys(key)) {
                    if (typeof key[k] === 'object') {
                        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                            if (!currentObject.hasOwnProperty(obj[k])) {
                                currentObject[obj[k]] = {};
                            }
                            currentObject = currentObject[obj[k]];
                            mergeObjectsByKey([obj], key[k], currentObject, level + 1);
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (Object.keys(key)[Object.keys(key).length - 1] === k) {
                            currentObject["HODNOTA"] = obj[k];
                            currentObject["META"] = null;
                            currentObject["NAZEV"] = k;
                        } else {
                            if (!currentObject.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
                                currentObject[k] = obj[k];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                newObjects.push(newObject);
            });
            return newObjects;
        }
```

**newObject** - the object that will be returned as the final object

**level** - a number that keeps track of the current level of nesting in the key object. It is used to determine if the current key in the **empty nested object** is a parent or child key

The function loops through each key in the **empty nested object**. If the current key is an object, it loops through each object in the **array of objects** and checks if the object has a key with the same name as the current key. If it does, it calls the function recursively with the current object, current key and current level+1 as the parameters. By doing this, it will check the next level of key object and compare it with the next level of the array of objects.

In the next level, it will again check if the key is an object or not. If it is an object, it will check if the key is already present in the current object or not. If it is not present, it will create a new property with the key and make it equal to an empty object.

Then it will call the function recursively with the current object, current key, and current level+1 as the parameters. If the key is not an object, it will check if it is the last key of the key object or not.

If it is the last key, it will add three properties HODNOTA, META and NAZEV to the current object.

If it is not the last key, it will add the key to the current object and make it equal to an array of values of the same key in the **array of objects**.

## **What I expected:**

the function will return final merged and structured objects in an array

## **What I got:**

array of objects of objects. Each object in array contain same number of objects, and all these objects in the array are same.

Inside objects of the array, each object has the name of value of "PERSON" that was used to merging.

In each PERSON object, there are objects named by all CRT values found for that PERSON value. Each CRT object is then empty.

I can see that partially it was merged succesfully, but from CRT the merging failed and lost the data.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's perfect, but it does something close. The technique here starts with `Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).map(...))` to modify the keys and values and build a new object based on the template object.

```
const TPL = {PERSON:null,CRT:{CRT_VALUE:{CRT:null,CODE:{CODE_VALUE:{CODE:null,DATA:{CODE:{VALUE:null,META:null,NAME:null},NAME:{VALUE:null,META:null,NAME:null},SUM:{VALUE:null,META:null,NAME:null},CONTEXT:{VALUE:null,META:null,NAME:null}}}}}}};
const values = [{PERSON:"21",CODE:"CMSS",CONTEXT:"",NAME:"SALARY",CRT:"Common",SUM:162000},{PERSON:"21",CODE:"DOS",CONTEXT:"",NAME:"TAX",CRT:"Common",SUM:192000},{PERSON:"21",CODE:"UPL",CONTEXT:"",NAME:"WAGE",CRT:"Other",SUM:255000},{PERSON:"22",CODE:"CMSS",CONTEXT:"",NAME:"SALARY",CRT:"Common",SUM:150000}];

function fillTpl(tpl, values, parentKey = '') {
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(tpl).map(([k, v]) => {
      if (k.endsWith('_VALUE')) k = values[k.slice(0, -6)];
      if (v == null) v = (k === 'VALUE') ? values[parentKey] : values[k];
      else v = fillTpl(v, values, k);
      return [k, v];
  }));
}

console.log(values.map(vals => fillTpl(TPL, vals)));
```

If you want to add new properties to the object, you can do like `Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).flatMap(([k, v]) => [[k, v], [k+'_2', v]]))`

Comment: Currently Im away from keyboard, but will have a look at the code as soon as possible!